JUunit test filtering in gradle like surefire
I have a 3 modules (one is build-logic) gradle project which has been migrated from maven (don't ask why:))
the thing is, in our ci we were able to filter tests using expressions like
<groups> tag1 & tag2</groups> or <groups>tag1, tag2</groups>
above as you can see, we filter the tests if they have both tags, that could have been '|' to make an OR condition.
So my question is, how can I have the same effect in gradle test filtering like surefire conditional expressions ?
I read some online guides and as you might guess the generative AI but non seems to be convincing my requirement.
This seems to be a very basic requirement and I am kinda shocked that gradle filtering does not support it yet.
